# Git subtree: move subtree to a different directory and pull it

Tags: git, git-subtree

Let's say I created a subtree like this:

```
git subtree --add --prefix=subdir <path_to_remote> <remote_branch> --squash
```

Then I wanted to move/rename subdir, so I do this:
`git mv subdir dir2/subdir`

Now when I try to pull that subtree to a new prefix:

```
git subtree --pull --prefix=dir2/subdir <path_to_remote> <remote_branch> --squash
```

git says:

```
Can't squash-merge: 'dir2/subdir' was never added.
```

How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `git subtree` command knows about your subtree, because it stores the name in the first commit when you `add` a subtree:

```
Add 'subdir/' from commit 'c7fbc973614eced220dcef1663d43dad90676e00'

git-subtree-dir: subdir
git-subtree-mainline: c166dc69165f6678d3c409df344c4ed9577a2e11
git-subtree-split: c7fbc973614eced220dcef1663d43dad90676e00
```

`git subtree pull` with the `--squash` option looks for a commit containing `git-subtree-dir` to find the most-recent commit from the remote repository and hence the point from which to apply and squash all commits.

In many cases a `git subtree split --rejoin` operation will be successful:

```
$ git subtree split --rejoin --prefix=dir2/subdir HEAD
Merge made by the 'ours' strategy.
25070c483647f8136655d0e0c6c3d62f469177aa
```

The resulting commit looks like:

```
Split 'dir2/subdir/' into commit '25070c483647f8136655d0e0c6c3d62f469177aa'

git-subtree-dir: dir2/subdir
git-subtree-mainline: 59cc3c770e78dbc30bdfe36a6b4e14ce83b38f6c
git-subtree-split: 25070c483647f8136655d0e0c6c3d62f469177aa
```

This commit will be found and the next `git subtree pull --squash` will succeed in most cases. Be aware that sometimes subtree operations fail and leave you with a branch of the subtree in your working copy of your repo. Make sure you delete any residual temporary branches to start with a clean slate.

Sometimes the above operation does not succeed, but I never found the reason why. In those cases you can rebase to the commit that added the subtree and change the directory name manually by amending the commit message.  This operation will corrupt your whole history for everybody else, though.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me! Since you said that git subtree just looks for text in the commit message, I tried to add necessary text to commit with rename but - as you said - ended with a branch of the subtree in my working copy.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer points out, the issue here is that git-subtree embeds the folder name into the commit, and refuses to acknowledge that you have renamed it. That answer suggests doing a split/rejoin which I think could end up making your commit history a little bloated and complicated.

A much simpler way is to make a simple commit to teach git-subtree to do the right thing.

1. Find the last commit that git-subtree did a squashed merge. I don't think git-subtree provides a native tool to do so, but one way to do it is by manually searching for it (assuming your folder is called "basedir"):

   ```
   git log -1 --grep "git-subtree-dir: basedir"
   ```

   It probably looks something like this in the end of the commit:

   ```
   git-subtree-dir: basedir
   git-subtree-split: 607efa887537d5544b3a99e2a0a2dd64abcc72ee
   ```

   You want to note the value of `git-subtree-split:` in the commit message. Let's say it is `607efa887537d5544b3a99e2a0a2dd64abcc72ee`.
2. Rename the folder like you were doing: `git mv basedir basedir2 && git commit`
3. Now, make an empty commit by doing the following (assuming you want to rename it to "basedir"):

   ```
   git commit --allow-empty
   ```

   Use the following commit message (you can customize it, of course):

   ```
   Reassign subtree dir from basedir to basedir2

   git-subtree-dir: basedir2
   git-subtree-split: 607efa887537d5544b3a99e2a0a2dd64abcc72ee
   ```

   Note that the hash `607efa887537d5544b3a99e2a0a2dd64abcc72ee` is the exact same one as the one before.

You are now good to go! You basically didn't do anything other than making an empty commit message and manually renamed `git-subtree-dir` from "basedir" to "basedir2". Git-subtree is kind of a simple tool in a way and will simply use that to remember what the subdir is. I feel like it should really include this as part of the tool instead of users needing to manually construct such a commit, but it works regardless (at least it worked when I was testing it out).

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance that the `git-subtree-*` metadata can be safely applied on a later commit. This happens a lot for us when using merge requests in gitlab when we forget to transport the metadata from the relevant commit